# Python Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, debugging, mergesort

Hi I am attempting to make a Merge Sort algorithm for fun, and do not want to just copy code off the internet. Which is why I have not referred to another person's Stack Overflow thread. So unless the thread has the same issue, please do not direct me towards that. I am using 2 functions, merge and merge sort. Merge sort is recursive, I intend for it to split a list in half, and then sort each half. The merge algorithm should then take the two sorted lists and return a new list, which is just the two lists combined and sorted. Eventually the code should return a fully sorted list. Below is my code, and if you run it you will see that I am getting an empty list returned, which makes no sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
def merge(left, right):
    resultList = []
    leastRight = 0
    leastLeft = 0
    if len(left) >= len(right):
        for i in range(len(left)-1):
            counter = 0
            for j in range(len(right)-1):
                counter += 1
                if right[counter % (len(right)-1)] <= right[j]:
                    leastRight = right[counter % (len(right)-1)]
                    print("leastRight if",leastRight)
                else:
                    leastRight = right[j]
                    print("leastRight else", leastRight)
                right.remove(leastRight)
            if left[i] <= leastRight:
                resultList.append(left[i])
            else:
                resultList.append(leastRight)
    else:
        for i in range(len(right)-1):
            counter = 0
            for j in range(len(left)-1):
                counter += 1
                if left[counter % (len(left)-1)] <= left[j]:
                    leastLeft = left[counter%(len(left)-1)]
                    print("leastLeft if", leastLeft)
                else:
                    leastLeft = left[j]
                    print("leastLeft else", leastLeft)
                left.remove(leastLeft)
            if right[i] <= leastLeft:
                resultList.append(right[i])
            else:
                resultList.append(leastLeft)
return (resultList)

def mergeSort(alist):

    print("alist", alist)
    if len(alist) > 2:
        middleIndex = len(alist) // 2
        sortedLeft = mergeSort(alist[:middleIndex])
        print("left", sortedLeft)
        sortedRight = mergeSort(alist[middleIndex:])
        print("right", sortedRight)
        result = merge(sortedLeft, sortedRight)
        print("result", result)
    else:
        result = alist
    return (result)

print("mergesort", mergeSort([6, 0, 2, 8, 9, 1]))
```

Comment: … where it would provoke advice like *rather than duplicate code with roles of variables swapped, swap their values*: `if len(left) >= len(right): left, right = right, left`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but approach of your merge function is not usable at all. Principle of choosing the smallest element is too tangled here and causes errors (I just saw it cannot merge [6] and [0,2]). Have you read classical description of merging?

In `mergesort` (we cannot omit treatment of length 2 lists):

```
if len(alist)   >=    2:
```

Quick-made working implementation of merge routine.

```
def merge(left, right):
    resultlist = []
    llen = len(left)
    rlen = len(right)
    il = 0
    ir = 0
    while il < llen and ir < rlen:  #while both list are not exhausted
        if left[il] <= right[ir]:    #choose the smallest current item
            resultlist.append(left[il])
            il += 1
        else:
            resultlist.append(right[ir])
            ir += 1
       #now treat the rest tail
    while il < llen:  
        resultlist.append(left[il])
        il += 1
    while ir < rlen:
        resultlist.append(right[ir])
        ir += 1
    return resultlist
```

result

```
>>> mergesort [0, 1, 2, 6, 8, 9]
```

Note it would be wise to make `resultlist` of known length for speed.

```
def merge(left, right):
    llen = len(left)
    rlen = len(right)
    resultlist = [0]*(llen+rlen) # we know data type and full length
    il = 0
    ir = 0
    k = 0
    while il < llen and ir < rlen:
        if left[il] <= right[ir]:
            resultlist[k] = left[il]
            il += 1
        else:
            resultlist[k] = right[ir]
            ir += 1
        k += 1
    while il < llen:
        resultlist[k] = left[il]
        il += 1
        k += 1
    while ir < rlen:
        resultlist[k] = right[ir]
        ir += 1
        k += 1
    return resultlist
```